# iLO 3 Firmware Update (HP Proliant DL380 G7)

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo, firmware

The iLO web interface allows me to upload a `.bin` file (*Obtain the firmware image (.bin) file from the Online ROM Flash Component for HP Integrated Lights-Out.*)

[image]

The iLO web interface redirects me to a page in the HP support website (http://www.hp.com/go/iLO) where I am supposed to find this `.bin` firmware, but no luck for me. The support website is a mess and very slow, badly categorized and generally unusable.

Where can I find this `.bin` file? The only related link I am able to find asks me about my server operating system (what does this have to do with the iLO?!) and lets me download an `.iso` with no `.bin` file

And also a related question: what is the latest iLO 3 version? (for Proliant DL380 G7, not sure if the iLO is tied to the server model)

Comment: Are you connecting from a Windows System?

Comment: Since the question was posted, HP has split into two companies, and the server business is now in the *HP Enterprise* company, or *hpe.com*. More specifically, [the iLO 3 firmware updates can be found here.](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/home/driverHome?sp4ts.oid=5294355&pmrsr=0)

Answer (score 9):

For Ubuntu there is no available firmware installer. Select the one for [RedHat](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4154847&swItemId=MTX_60584a6af22849f49a0cee6506&swEnvOid=4103#). You will get an `.scexe` file, which you can [unpack](http://www.popmartian.com/tipsntricks/2014/01/17/how-to-extract-the-contents-of-a-scexe-file/):

```
$ chmod 740 CP022551.scexe
$ ./CP022551.scexe  --unpack=/tmp/iLO3
$ ls -l /tmp/iLO3
CP022551.xml
flash_ilo3
ilo3_180.bin
README.TXT
```

There you have it: a `ilo3_180.bin` which you can upload with your iLO 3 web interface.

Comment: If you're running Linux, you can just install directly from the command line. Running `./CP022551.scexe` installs the firmware, provided you have the HP Management Agents installed (which you should).

Comment: Having Ubuntu as host OS, and being Ubuntu badly supported by HP, I doubt that I have any "Management Agent" (never heard of it) installed. I have just vanilla Ubuntu running. Anyway, just for upgrading the iLO firmware it is too much hassle to care about that many moving parts. Get .bin file, upload with web interface, and *bum*, iLO firmware upgraded. That easy!

Comment: This means you're missing hardware status, email and SNMP alerts, fan speed and temperature control and a conduit between the ILO and OS for health monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider installing that (if I ever get it running for Ubuntu)

Comment: Download the [HP Management Control Pack for Ubuntu](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swItemId=MTX_1e1703e5109e47ad8c6adda551&swEnvOid=4144#tab3).

Comment: @ewwhite I don't think the agent it required. It's not installed on my openSUSE server and I can simply execute the file to perform the firmware update (after running `chmod +x` on the file first).

Answer (score 7):

For convenience, the latest versions of the firmware are being tracked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out, and independently by http://pingtool.org/latest-hp-ilo-firmwares/.

At time of writing (Jan 2022), they are:

- ILO1 : [ilo196.bin](https://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-ilo/p1980791503/v97349/CP023365.scexe) (30-Apr-2014) ([Search](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?kmpmoid=397990&tab=driversAndSoftware))
- ILO2 : [ilo2_233.bin](https://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-ilo/p915269625/v148520/CP035238.scexe) (30-Mar-2018) ([Search](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?kmpmoid=2511402&tab=driversAndSoftware))
- ILO3 : [ilo3_194.bin](https://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-ilo/p1573561412/v189986/CP046328.scexe) (iLO3 v 1.94, 17-Dec-2020) ([Search](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?kmpmoid=5294355&tab=driversAndSoftware))
- ILO4 : [ilo4_279.bin](https://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-ilo/p192122427/v204995/CP049647.scexe) (iLO4 v 2.79, 16-Nov-2020) ([Search](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?kmpmoid=1009143853&tab=driversAndSoftware))
- ILO5 : [ilo5_235.bin](https://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-ilo/p1342933511/v204064/RPMS/x86_64/firmware-ilo5-2.60-1.1.x86_64.rpm) (iLO5 v 2.60, 06-Dec-2021) ([Search](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?kmpmoid=1010145741&tab=driversAndSoftware))

*(If this list gets out of date, check the above two links at the top of this post, or the Search links above, which will hopefully continue to work for the foreseeable future.  I've made this Community Wiki, so anyone can easily update it if they want.)*

The links are direct download for `.scexe` files.  They are `tar.gz` archives prepended by a shell script, but can be detected and extracted by 7-Zip.  Inside there is a `.bin` file, which you can extract and upload directly to the iLO.

There doesn't seem to be an scexe download for ILO5 any more.  The link above is for a `.rpm`, which can also be extracted with 7-Zip, then just drill down to the .bin file at `[…].cpio/./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/firmware-ilo5-[…]/ilo5_[…].bin`.

Answer (score 4):

[**Online ROM Flash Component for Windows - HP Integrated Lights-Out 3**](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swItemId=MTX_8d5e3a88ef9f4c26a1f5c2c1f2&swEnvOid=4064)

[*(changelog is here)*](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swItemId=MTX_8d5e3a88ef9f4c26a1f5c2c1f2&swEnvOid=4064#tab-history)

Download from HP and extract to your PC. You'll see a .bin file in the resulting directory. You can upload that to the ILO firmware page.

---

You can update all of the system firmware using the HP Service Pack for ProLiant (HP SPP) DVD download. You can update ILO firmware from the host server's operating system using the appropriate ILO package for the running OS. Windows is linked above. [Linux is linked here](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swItemId=MTX_60584a6af22849f49a0cee6506&swEnvOid=4103).

All drivers and downloads for the [DL380 G7 are here](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=4091567&lang=en&lang=en&cc=us&cc=us).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am connecting from a linux (Ubuntu) system. Do you have a link to an Ubuntu installer? Is there no direct link to the .bin firmware, which is (I presume) OS independent?

Comment: No. I don't have a link to the .bin file. You'll need to extract it. I'm trying to give the path of least resistance. If you have a Windows computer somewhere, you can extract the file linked above and connect to the ILO from there. Otherwise, I'll need more details about the system...

Comment: Thanks, I found it myself. The problem all along was that I was selecting my OS (Ubuntu 12.04) and apparently HP does not offer a firmware installer for Ubuntu. Now I have selected Red Hat and there it is: an installer (.scexe executable) which I can unpack. My confusion comes from the fact that I did not know what to expect, and that selecting my host OS was offering some downloads, but no firmware and no firmware installer. Now the iLO is updating, hopefully without problems.

Comment: Ubuntu is not really a good OS for HP ProLiant hardware. It's not as well supported (*this question is a good example*) and tends to have more compatibility and runtime issues than the operating systems HP chooses to focus on. Perhaps that's wrong on HP's side, but it's the current situation. Good luck!

Comment: Yes it has! Successfully upgraded from 1.28 to 1.80! I'll post what I did for reference for others

Comment: I have never used HP support before (which I am glad of), but now I see that Ubuntu is just second citizen for them. On the other hand, I have been running Ubuntu (10.04 and 12.04) for years without issues in this HP Proliant DL380 G7

Answer (score 3):

While struggling with the same problems on HP's website I too found it incredibly difficult to find a specific .bin version. I was going to create a library of bin files, but someone else beat me too it. This site is hosting .bin files for several ilo versions.

http://pingtool.org/latest-hp-ilo-firmwares/

<sub>* other than using that page myself I'm not affiliated.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Latest firmware can be found here:
http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c05249760 
If you have a firmware prior to 1.20 version you have to upgrade to 1.20 first:
https://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_bb45e0682dd04f098ad89e189c#tab3